# cannot find symbol variable FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Tags: android

After updating support version to 27.0.0 compiler giving error

`cannot find symbol variable FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`.

> Is this variable removed? 
>   What use instead?

code example:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SetNewPasswordActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: why IntentCompat ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> cannot find symbol variable FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

You should use [**`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to
>   be cleared before the activity is started.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Answer (score 2):

`IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is deprecated thus please use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` directly.

This flag can only be used in conjunction with `#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

instead of this

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove this line

> IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

- add this

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Comment: remove `you have to downgrade your gradle to 27 to 25`

Answer (score 0):

[IntentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html) doesn't have any flag like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`.

You should use **Intent** instead.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: Maybe, but it have worked before updating the support version!

Comment: The link I have added for IntentCompat class reference never said that it had that flag. You might be doing something else that time